# Hallengreen's Index maintenance query not using all indexes

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using [Hallengreen's Index maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) To reorganize/rebuild indexes on my databases.

The problem is, when I execute it:

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'MyDatabase',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30
```

It only finds 2 or 3 indexes (On Messages Window). And I have a lot of them with more than 90% fragmentation:

[image]

Is there some information I'm missing?

Maybe there are not enough pages, so there's no performance impact, and then the script just skips the index ( the first index has 240 pages)?

Comment: There is a variable in the script. Something like 'do not rebuild indexes with less then 1000 pages' - this is the default. You can open the script and see it for yourself. This might be the problem

Comment: Oh, Maybe `@PageCountLevel int = 1000,` ?

Comment: From the documentation regarding parameter "PageCountLevel" - "Set a size, in pages; indexes with fewer pages are skipped for index maintenance. The default is 1000 pages. This is based on Microsoft’s recommendation." - what happens if you manually provide this parameter with a lower value?

Comment: @Rafael Piccinelli, exactly

Comment: Oh I didnt change it. I was just confused. with <1000 it executes with all index. Simple variable I didn't notice. Maybe we can close this question, or answer it @smokingDBA.

Comment: It also won't rebuild HEAPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a variable in the script. Something like 'do not rebuild indexes with less then 1000 pages' - this is the default.
Its name `@PageCountLevel`

You can change it to whatever you wish.